# Comparing C# records with other types using Equals(object) method

Tags: c#, record, equality

In C# the `object.Equals(object?)` virtual method of the `record` types is generated by the compiler automatically. The generated method looks like:

```cs
    [IsReadOnly]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is MyRecord)
        {
            return Equals((MyRecord)obj);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But what if the record implements other `IEquatalbe<T>` interfaces:

```cs
public readonly record struct MyRecord : IEquatable<int>
{
    // ....

    public bool Equals(int other)
    {
         return Whatever();
    }
}
```

In this case, the the `int` values do not considered by the `Equals(object?)` method and libraries using the `Equals(object?)` don't not work properly (like FluentAssertions):

```cs
   myRecord.Should().Be(4); // will never pass
```

Is there any solution to customize the `Equals(object?)` method for the `record` types?

I tried to override the `Equals(object)` method in the record, but the compiler generated an error:

```
  Error CS0111: Type 'MyRecord' already defines a member called 'Equals' with the same parameter types
```

Comment: why does your record impklement `IEquatable<int>` instead of `IEquatbale<MyRecord>`? That implies some implicit type-cast which isn't what equality is about.

Comment: Fundamentally, it's *really* odd for a type to implement `IEquatable<T>` for a type other than itself. Aside from anything else, why would you want `x.Equals(y)` and `y.Equals(x)` to give different results? That's a recipe for hard-to-diagnose breakages IMO.